# Hadoop dfs -ls returns list of files in my hadoop/ dir

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I've set up a sigle-node Hadoop configuration running via cygwin under Win7. After starting Hadoop by

```
bin/start-all.sh
```

I run

```
bin/hadoop dfs -ls
```

which returns me a list of files in my hadoop directory. Then I run

```
bin/hadoop datanode -format
bin/hadoop namenode -format
```

but -ls still returns me the contents of my hadoop directory. As far as I understand it should return nothing(empty folder). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Did you edit the core-site.xml and mapred-site.xml under conf folder ?
It seems like your hadoop cluster is in local mode.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question is quite old, but directory structure in Hadoop has changed a bit (version 2.5 )
Jeroen's current version would be.

**hdfs dfs -ls hdfs://localhost:9000/users/smalldata**

Also Just for information - use of start-all.sh and stop-all.sh has been deprecated, instead one should use start-dfs.sh and start-yarn.sh

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by explicitly specifying the URL to the NameNode.

To list all directories in the root of your hdfs space do the following:

```
./bin/hadoop dfs -ls hdfs://<ip-of-your-server>:9000/
```

The documentation says something about a default hdfs point in the configuration, but I cannot find it. If someone knows what they mean please enlighten us.

This is where I got the info: http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.20.0/hdfs_shell.html#Overview

Answer (score 1):

Or you could just do:

- Run stop-all.sh.
- Remove dfs data and name directories
- Namenode -format
- Run start-all.sh